# Attribute to declare that a method always throws an exception, to satisfy BC42105

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, compiler-warnings

Compiler Warning BC42105 occurs when there are branches in a function that will not return a value or throw an exception. However, I have a situation where I throw the exception in a called method and it will always throw. The code analysis does not appear to detect this, and I can't find an attribute that will ensure that the compiler error doesn't have to be manually suppressed.

In VB.Net, using .NET 7.

Desired code:

```
Private ReadOnly cgItems As IDictionary(Of Integer, Item)

Public Function GetItem(itemID as Integer) As Item
    Dim item as Item = Nothing

    If cgItems.TryGetValue(itemID, item) tThen
        Return item
    Else
        ThrowItemDoesntExist(itemID)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub ThrowItemDoesntExist(itemID As Integer)
    Throw New ArgumentException($"The Item ID #{itemID} does not exist.", NameOf(itemID))
End Sub
```

The `ThrowItemDoesntExist` method is called from a number of places where this sort of check is done, so having a single method allows for conformity and easy code maintenance.

However, `GetItem` raises the BC42105 warning because the `ThrowItemDoesntExist` has no way of indicating that it always throws an `Exception`.

**Current workaround**

My current workaround, which is a bit kludgy is using the `<DoesNotReturn>` `CodeAnalysis` attribute.  And it works, but it *feels* wrong.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis

Private ReadOnly cgItems As IDictionary(Of Integer, Item)

Public Function GetItem(itemID as Integer) As Item
    Dim item as Item = Nothing

    If cgItems.TryGetValue(itemID, item) tThen
        Return item
    Else
        Return ThrowItemDoesntExist(itemID)
    End If
End Function

<DoesNotReturn>
Private Function ThrowItemDoesntExist(itemID As Integer)
    Throw New ArgumentException($"The Item ID #{itemID} does not exist.", NameOf(itemID))
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis). It specifically says that the meaning of that attribute is "A method or property never returns. In other words, it always throws an exception". That's exactly what you want so it's exactly right.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - That's why I used it, but I'm trying to avoid having to format it *as if* it returns something.  Just applying the Attribute does not disperse the warning.  It has to be reformatted as `Returns ThrowItemDoesntExist` and `ThrowItemDoesntExist` made a function to disperse that warning.  If I put the attribute on the caller function, it's inaccurate, because when the item exists it does return.  If the workaround is the way it's "supposed to work", then it's a clunky implementation, but so be it.

Comment: My guess would be that code analysis just looks at the body of each method in isolation, rather than looking inside methods that that method calls. It can see each called method from the outside, which is why attributes work, but if it looked inside those methods then where would it end? That would be much more work and so create performance issues.